# Traffic lights using setAtrribute with 3 images

Tags: javascript, image, onclick, attributes, setattribute

I need help with my task to do traffic lights using set attribute and 3 images of the traffic lights.

This is what I have so far:

```
<img src="theImage" alt="red.jpg">

<p><input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="pictureChange()"></p>
```

```js
var lights = ["red.jpg", "amber.jpg", "green.jpg"]

function pictureChange(){
  // line 18:
  document.getElementById("theImage").setAttribute(lights, "amber.jpg");
}
```

Line 18 is wrong according to the Google Chrome console but I can't find the resolution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your set attribute you need to put lights in quotes. It's a string attribute name.

```
document.getElementById('theImage').setAttribute('lights','amber.jpg');
```

**Edit:**
Now that I look at it, I think you want the traffic light to change with each click of that button. Here's what I'd do

```
var lights = ["red.jpg","amber.jpg","green.jpg"]
var lightCounter=0;
function pictureChange(){
lightCounter+=1; //Increase the lightCounter by 1;
 document.getElementById('theImage').src=lights[lightCounter];//Set the source of the image to be an element in the array pointed at by the light counter
}
```

Comment: I did that but when i press the button the image doesnt change, there is no syntax errors in the console but still doesnt work?

Comment: It's not a syntax error, you're code just doesn't do what you want. I've updated my answer, it should help you.

Comment: Ok thanks, it worked but do you have a webpage or something which can tell me how this all works? thanks again

Comment: Not quite, it just takes practice. I suggest codeacademy.com if you're getting started. But most of it you just learn as you go. Select this as the answer to close this question.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much for your help, this helped me alot, now i dont have to ask my friends for help and try to finish the code for another 2 days. :)